# How to extract a variable assignment from within a string

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am trying to extract a variable assignment from a file that is defined within a larger string in an external file /home/user/file.txt:

```
export OS_USERNAME=XXXXX
```

I want to "source" the file and pull the variable assignment so that my script treats it as:

```
OS_USERNAME=XXXXX
```

I then will pipe this variable into another command that I am running on my script.

```
config -- "$OS_USERNAME" --test --run
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can pull this variable assignment from the external file?

Comment: Just to be clear the file I am pulling from that has the variable string is: `/home/user/file.txt`. The file I am running for my script is `/root/script.sh`.  Hope that helps make things clear.

Comment: Anytime you source the file (via `. file.txt`), you should have the variables.

Comment: Yeah I try that but, I think the fact that the "export" occurs on the same line. It doesn't extract the variable assignment the way I want it to.

Comment: The `export` is exactly what you need. Just source the file and try to `echo` the variable.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: You're right I see it worked! Thank yoU! Eureka!

Comment: I've added a full example in my answer.

Comment: If you *really* didn't want a name exported, you can run `declare +x OS_USERNAME` after sourcing the file to "unexpert" it.

Answer (score 2):

In you script

```
#! /bin/bash

source /path/to/file.txt
# your variables are set
command
command
...
```